# Switch case issue(Android)

Tags: android

I am creating project of bouncing balls in which I take input from the user the number 
of balls he/she want to bounce.Then I am using switch case to write further code according to number user entered.When I am not using switch case and executing the project without taking input from user according to number of balls I want to bounce it works well..but with switch case it creates problem..when i open the screen which should display balls bouncing it shows error"Unfortunately,application has stopped"...Here is the code part which creates problem..

```
package com.example.preliminarytest;
import android.content.Context;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;
public class AnimationView extends View{
  private final int FRAME_RATE=15;
  private Paint paint;
  private Handler h;
  Ball myball;
  Ball greenball;
  Ball redball;
  Ball cyanball;
  Ball yellowball;
  Ball greyball;
  Ball magentaball;
  Ball grey;
  int value;
  public void setString(int value)
  {
     this.value = value;
     System.out.println("value="+value);
  }

    public AnimationView(Context context,AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context,attrs);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

        h=new Handler();
        paint=new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        switch(value)
        {
        case 1:
            myball=new Ball(100,100,Color.BLUE,50);
            myball.setDX(10);
            myball.setDY(10);
            break;
        case 2:
            myball=new Ball(100,100,Color.BLUE,50);
            greenball=new Ball(200,200,Color.GREEN,50);
            myball.setDX(10);
            myball.setDY(10);
            greenball.setDX(10);
            greenball.setDY(10);
            break;
        case 3:
            myball=new Ball(100,100,Color.BLUE,50);
            greenball=new Ball(200,200,Color.GREEN,50);
            redball=new Ball(50,400,Color.RED,50);
            myball.setDX(10);
            myball.setDY(10);
            greenball.setDX(10);
            greenball.setDY(10);
            redball.setDX(10);
            redball.setDY(10);
            break;
        case 4:
            myball=new Ball(100,100,Color.BLUE,50);
            greenball=new Ball(200,200,Color.GREEN,50);
            redball=new Ball(50,400,Color.RED,50);
            cyanball=new Ball(100,300,Color.CYAN,50);
            myball.setDX(10);
            myball.setDY(10);
            greenball.setDX(10);
            greenball.setDY(10);
            redball.setDX(10);
            redball.setDY(10);
            cyanball.setDX(10);
            cyanball.setDY(10);
            break;
        case 5:
            myball=new Ball(100,100,Color.BLUE,50);
            greenball=new Ball(200,200,Color.GREEN,50);
            redball=new Ball(50,400,Color.RED,50);
            cyanball=new Ball(100,300,Color.CYAN,50);
            yellowball=new Ball(10,300,Color.YELLOW,50);
            myball.setDX(10);
            myball.setDY(10);
            greenball.setDX(10);
            greenball.setDY(10);
            redball.setDX(10);
            redball.setDY(10);
            cyanball.setDX(10);
            cyanball.setDY(10);
            yellowball.setDX(10);
            yellowball.setDY(10);
            break;
        case 6: 
            myball=new Ball(100,100,Color.BLUE,50);
            greenball=new Ball(200,200,Color.GREEN,50);
            redball=new Ball(50,400,Color.RED,50);
            cyanball=new Ball(100,300,Color.CYAN,50);
            yellowball=new Ball(10,300,Color.YELLOW,50);
            magentaball=new Ball(150,300,Color.MAGENTA,50);
            myball.setDX(10);
            myball.setDY(10);
            greenball.setDX(10);
            greenball.setDY(10);
            redball.setDX(10);
            redball.setDY(10);
            cyanball.setDX(10);
            cyanball.setDY(10);
            yellowball.setDX(10);
            yellowball.setDY(10);
            magentaball.setDX(10);
            magentaball.setDY(10);
            break;
        case 7:
            myball=new Ball(100,100,Color.BLUE,50);
            greenball=new Ball(200,200,Color.GREEN,50);
            redball=new Ball(50,400,Color.RED,50);
            cyanball=new Ball(100,300,Color.CYAN,50);
            yellowball=new Ball(10,300,Color.YELLOW,50);
            magentaball=new Ball(150,300,Color.MAGENTA,50);
            grey=new Ball(100,150,Color.GRAY,50);
            myball.setDX(10);
            myball.setDY(10);
            greenball.setDX(10);
            greenball.setDY(10);
            redball.setDX(10);
            redball.setDY(10);
            cyanball.setDX(10);
            cyanball.setDY(10);
            yellowball.setDX(10);
            yellowball.setDY(10);
            magentaball.setDX(10);
            magentaball.setDY(10);
            grey.setDX(10);
            grey.setDY(10);
            break;
            default:System.out.println("invalid value");


        }



    }
    protected void onDraw(Canvas c)
    {
        switch(value)
        {
        case 1:
            myball.bounce(c);
            c.drawCircle(myball.getX(), myball.getY(),myball.getRadius(), myball.getPaint());
            break;
        case 2:
            myball.bounce(c);
            greenball.bounce(c);
            c.drawCircle(myball.getX(), myball.getY(),myball.getRadius(), myball.getPaint());
            c.drawCircle(greenball.getX(), greenball.getY(),greenball.getRadius(), greenball.getPaint());
            break;
        case 3:
            myball.bounce(c);
            greenball.bounce(c);
            redball.bounce(c);
            c.drawCircle(myball.getX(), myball.getY(),myball.getRadius(), myball.getPaint());
            c.drawCircle(greenball.getX(), greenball.getY(),greenball.getRadius(), greenball.getPaint());
            c.drawCircle(redball.getX(), redball.getY(),redball.getRadius(), redball.getPaint());
            break;
        case 4:
            myball.bounce(c);
            greenball.bounce(c);
            redball.bounce(c);
            cyanball.bounce(c);
            c.drawCircle(myball.getX(), myball.getY(),myball.getRadius(), myball.getPaint());
            c.drawCircle(greenball.getX(), greenball.getY(),greenball.getRadius(), greenball.getPaint());
            c.drawCircle(redball.getX(), redball.getY(),redball.getRadius(), redball.getPaint());
            c.drawCircle(cyanball.getX(), cyanball.getY(),cyanball.getRadius(), cyanball.getPaint());
            break;
        case 5:
            myball.bounce(c);
            greenball.bounce(c);
            redball.bounce(c);
            cyanball.bounce(c);
            yellowball.bounce(c);
            c.drawCircle(myball.getX(), myball.getY(),myball.getRadius(), myball.getPaint());
            c.drawCircle(greenball.getX(), greenball.getY(),greenball.getRadius(), greenball.getPaint());
            c.drawCircle(redball.getX(), redball.getY(),redball.getRadius(), redball.getPaint());
            c.drawCircle(cyanball.getX(), cyanball.getY(),cyanball.getRadius(), cyanball.getPaint());
            c.drawCircle(yellowball.getX(), yellowball.getY(),yellowball.getRadius(), yellowball.getPaint());
            break;
        case 6:

            myball.bounce(c);
            greenball.bounce(c);
            redball.bounce(c);
            cyanball.bounce(c);
            yellowball.bounce(c);
            magentaball.bounce(c);
            c.drawCircle(myball.getX(), myball.getY(),myball.getRadius(), myball.getPaint());
            c.drawCircle(greenball.getX(), greenball.getY(),greenball.getRadius(), greenball.getPaint());
            c.drawCircle(redball.getX(), redball.getY(),redball.getRadius(), redball.getPaint());
            c.drawCircle(cyanball.getX(), cyanball.getY(),cyanball.getRadius(), cyanball.getPaint());
            c.drawCircle(yellowball.getX(), yellowball.getY(),yellowball.getRadius(), yellowball.getPaint());
            c.drawCircle(myball.getX(), myball.getY(),myball.getRadius(), myball.getPaint());
            c.drawCircle(greenball.getX(), greenball.getY(),greenball.getRadius(), greenball.getPaint());
            c.drawCircle(redball.getX(), redball.getY(),redball.getRadius(), redball.getPaint());
            c.drawCircle(cyanball.getX(), cyanball.getY(),cyanball.getRadius(), cyanball.getPaint());
            c.drawCircle(magentaball.getX(), magentaball.getY(),magentaball.getRadius(), magentaball.getPaint());
            break;

        case 7:
            myball.bounce(c);
            greenball.bounce(c);
            redball.bounce(c);
            cyanball.bounce(c);
            yellowball.bounce(c);
            magentaball.bounce(c);
            greyball.bounce(c);
            c.drawCircle(myball.getX(), myball.getY(),myball.getRadius(), myball.getPaint());
            c.drawCircle(greenball.getX(), greenball.getY(),greenball.getRadius(), greenball.getPaint());
            c.drawCircle(redball.getX(), redball.getY(),redball.getRadius(), redball.getPaint());
            c.drawCircle(cyanball.getX(), cyanball.getY(),cyanball.getRadius(), cyanball.getPaint());
            c.drawCircle(yellowball.getX(), yellowball.getY(),yellowball.getRadius(), yellowball.getPaint());
            c.drawCircle(myball.getX(), myball.getY(),myball.getRadius(), myball.getPaint());
            c.drawCircle(greenball.getX(), greenball.getY(),greenball.getRadius(), greenball.getPaint());
            c.drawCircle(redball.getX(), redball.getY(),redball.getRadius(), redball.getPaint());
            c.drawCircle(cyanball.getX(), cyanball.getY(),cyanball.getRadius(), cyanball.getPaint());
            c.drawCircle(magentaball.getX(), magentaball.getY(),magentaball.getRadius(), magentaball.getPaint());
            c.drawCircle(greyball.getX(), greyball.getY(),greyball.getRadius(), greyball.getPaint());
            break;
        default:System.out.println("invalid value");
        }

h.postDelayed(r, FRAME_RATE);

    }
    private Runnable r=new Runnable()
    { public void run()
    { invalidate();
    }
    };
    }
```

And here is the errors shown on Logcat

```
04-08 17:37:55.288: E/AndroidRuntime(685): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-08 17:37:55.288: E/AndroidRuntime(685): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-08 17:37:55.288: E/AndroidRuntime(685):  at com.example.preliminarytest.AnimationView.onDraw(AnimationView.java:162)
04-08 17:37:55.288: E/AndroidRuntime(685):  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13458)
04-08 17:37:55.288: E/AndroidRuntime(685):  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13342)
04-08 17:37:55.288: E/AndroidRuntime(685):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2929)
04-08 17:37:55.288: E/AndroidRuntime(685):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2799)
04-08 17:37:55.288: E/AndroidRuntime(685):  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13340)
04-08 17:37:55.288: E/AndroidRuntime(685):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2929)
04-08 17:37:55.288: E/AndroidRuntime(685):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2799)
04-08 17:37:55.288: E/AndroidRuntime(685):  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13461)
04-08 17:37:55.288: E/AndroidRuntime(685):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:467)
04-08 17:37:55.288: E/AndroidRuntime(685):  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13342)
04-08 17:37:55.288: E/AndroidRuntime(685):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2929)
04-08 17:37:55.288: E/AndroidRuntime(685):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2799)
04-08 17:37:55.288: E/AndroidRuntime(685):  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13340)
04-08 17:37:55.288: E/AndroidRuntime(685):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2929)
04-08 17:37:55.288: E/AndroidRuntime(685):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2799)
04-08 17:37:55.288: E/AndroidRuntime(685):  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13461)
04-08 17:37:55.288: E/AndroidRuntime(685):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:467)
04-08 17:37:55.288: E/AndroidRuntime(685):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:2183)
04-08 17:37:55.288: E/AndroidRuntime(685):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.drawSoftware(ViewRootImpl.java:2258)
04-08 17:37:55.288: E/AndroidRuntime(685):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2153)
04-08 17:37:55.288: E/AndroidRuntime(685):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2021)
04-08 17:37:55.288: E/AndroidRuntime(685):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1832)
04-08 17:37:55.288: E/AndroidRuntime(685):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1000)
04-08 17:37:55.288: E/AndroidRuntime(685):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4214)
04-08 17:37:55.288: E/AndroidRuntime(685):  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
04-08 17:37:55.288: E/AndroidRuntime(685):  at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
04-08 17:37:55.288: E/AndroidRuntime(685):  at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525)
04-08 17:37:55.288: E/AndroidRuntime(685):  at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
04-08 17:37:55.288: E/AndroidRuntime(685):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
04-08 17:37:55.288: E/AndroidRuntime(685):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-08 17:37:55.288: E/AndroidRuntime(685):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-08 17:37:55.288: E/AndroidRuntime(685):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
04-08 17:37:55.288: E/AndroidRuntime(685):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-08 17:37:55.288: E/AndroidRuntime(685):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-08 17:37:55.288: E/AndroidRuntime(685):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
04-08 17:37:55.288: E/AndroidRuntime(685):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
04-08 17:37:55.288: E/AndroidRuntime(685):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: well, your class constructor is calling switch-case statement, at this moment ur value has not been initializes. Make sure that , ur switch-case should run only after when ur value get initialized.

Comment: you have problem in `myball.bounce(c);` check `myball` and `c`on line 162: `java.lang.NullPointerException
04-08 17:37:55.288: E/AndroidRuntime(685):  at com.example.preliminarytest.AnimationView.onDraw(AnimationView.java:162)`

Comment: Are you sure `value` is never null?

Comment: Your initialize a new ball object on every switch case, check if no one is null while drawing over the Canvas, set value to 1 by default.

Comment: @Abhishek choudhary  I think u r right! value is initialized using setString() method but it is called only after class constructor.So switch is receiving null value..Can u help me how can i call setString() method before switch..If i write the method inside constructor it shows error and if i make it static it again shows error..Anyway thanks for ur answer..

Comment: @Andy how could `value` ever be null, it's `int`...

Comment: Forget the `value`, this crash is about what @shayanpourvatan said.

Comment: i don't think there is any problem wth myball.bounce(c)..just bcoz its first statement of switch error is coming..main problem is that value is not initialized before calling switch..

Comment: when creating that class, the `value` gets its default **value** which is ZERO (=0). Take a look at this http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

Comment: yupp..but i don't want value zero for value.....i have created a method for assigning value to value..nd tht method should be called before switch..

Comment: Still your main problem is that null pointer at line 162 !

Comment: got it right now.. i use switch inside method rather than constructor and called that method inside setString() method

Answer (score 0):

There is something null as it is clearly written in logcat output. NullPointerException at line no 162 of AnimationView.java. Please check this line. may be you are using some variable that is never initialized.

Answer (score 0):

Hey you are getting `NullPonterException` in onDraw() method. You can do something like this to avoid crashing of app.

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas c)
{
if(value>0){
Log.e("Value","Value ="+value);
    switch(value)
    {
     // your code.
    }
}
else{
Log.e("Exception","Null Value");
}
```

This will avoid crashing of your app.

Comment: `value` is int, it can not be null and this code should generate compile error